# what does this line mean in reflection

Tags: java, reflection

```
new Class[]{String.class}
```

What does this line mean actually,why do we write String.class when we pass as an argument in getDeclaredConstructor() method? and why we pass it as Class array?

Comment: getDeclaredConstructor accepts `Class...`. In Java `...` represents [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) which represents array of specific type (in case of `Class...` array of Class objects. You could simply use `String.class, Integer.class` if your constructor would require String and Integer arguments.

Comment: @Holger i would have if someone would have answered that part of my question

Comment: @user3380123 The documentation for `Class.getDeclaredConstructor` answers that part.

Comment: @user3380123 This part was not in your original question, you just asked it in comment first and then moved to question after it was already answered.

Answer (score 3):

That creates an array of type `Class` that contains a single element, a `Class` object for the `String` class.

[`Class#getDeclaredConstructor(..)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredConstructor%28java.lang.Class...%29) javadoc states

> Returns a `Constructor` object that reflects the specified constructor
>   of the class or interface represented by this Class object. **The
>   `parameterTypes` parameter is an array of `Class` objects that identify
>   the constructor's formal parameter types, in declared order.** If this
>   `Class` object represents an inner class declared in a non-static
>   context, the formal parameter types include the explicit enclosing
>   instance as the first parameter.

You need to pass in the appropriate `Class` objects for the corresponding parameters types. The method uses those types to determine the appropriate constructor.